# Insert a variable into a template literal href tag

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am trying reference set up an `href` tag in a template literal using a dynamically generated variable pulled from an AJAX request but can't seem to figure it out. Nothing happens when I click the tagged element and for some reason the `<a href/>` doesn't show up when I inspect the element on the webpage.

Here is my code:

```
[...]  

data.forEach(([cafeId, cafeName, cafeAddress]) => {
            var myCol = $('<div id="col"></div>');
            var myPanel = $(
              `
              <div class="card-group">
              <div class="card card-block m-3 overflow-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title venue-name" id=\"` + cafeName + `\"><a href="venue/\"` + cafeId + `\"></a></h5>
                  <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted venue-address"></h6>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="venue-options" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"><a id="share" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Share</a><a id="addToListNoModal" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add to List</a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            `
            );
[...]
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50pwyfde/12/

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem, but the whole point of template literals is you don't have to concatenate strings: `'some text' + var + 'more text'` is more readably written as `some text${var}more text` (with backticks surrounding the whole thing)

Comment: You don't need to escape the quotes inside template literals. But it doesn't seem to cause a problem, either, so that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong number of quotes in the `<a>` element. You're creating something that looks like

```
<a href="venue/"cafeId">
```

The extra quote is causing everything after it to parse incorrectly.

Change that whole line to:

```
<h5 class="card-title venue-name" id="${cafeName}"><a href="venue/${cafeId}"></a></h5>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the response, I do this but the link still does not work, nor does the ``<a>`` element appear in the console when I inspect the ``venue-name`` element.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] so I can run it and see the result?

Comment: You have no text in the link, what do you want to click on? Although it still should appear in the console.

Comment: That’s the strange thing, I I thought the link text would be the h5 element text. I’ll get a minimal reproducible example set up. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It should be the other way around: `<a ...><h5>text</h5></a>`

Comment: You have no text in the `h5`, either.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `<a...>${cafeName}</a>`

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle to the OP. Thanks again.

Comment: `$(".venue-name", myPanel).html(cafeName)` replaces the anchor with `cafeName`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one double quote too much:

```html
`<a href="venue/\"` + cafeId + `\"></a>`
```

It has to be:

```html
`<a href="venue/` + cafeId + `\"></a>`
```

Also, the template literals syntax allows you to embedd your variables instead of concatinating multiple strings.

Like:

```html
`<a href="venue/${cafeId}"></a>`
```

Checkout this good documentation about template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals